# Handling two Flyouts(Mat-Sidenavs) in angular material and angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm relatively new to angular, I have three components PanelComponent (in which there are two buttons one for comments and another for Advisor) and those two buttons should be floating on the screen,CommentsComponent and AdvisorComponent

My Question is If I click on each button a new sidenav should appear like if I click on Comments button a sidenav with CommentsComponent and respectively, any ideas are welcome please?

Comment: The Angular Material examples include one with two drawers as well as one that opens or closes via a button. If there's something specific that you don't understand, please tell us. https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples

Comment: I would like to have both the sidenavs on the same position, If one is open other should be closed.

Comment: Use the same 'position' for both (start or end). When you open one, close the other - do both in the callback attached to the button.